# Is there a case where something turned out to be division by zero?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Is there any famous or controversial case in science where the proof was scrutinized and turned out to be an error like a division by zero?

Comment: There's Kempe's "proof" of the four color theorem, which you can read about [here](http://web.stonehill.edu/compsci/lc/four-color/four-color.htm). But I really wouldn't call it a "grotesque error". Just a subtle mistake which completely invalidated the argument.

Comment: Interesting! Tks. I will edit the question to remove the word ”grotesque”. I realize now that it is not adequate

Comment: In that case, after removing the flawed section the remaining parts of the proof were able to prove that 4 colors suffice. I am looking for something that was completely rejected afterward

Comment: Why would division by zero automatically be an error.  Ask a [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory).

Comment: I don't think Kempe's proof was repairable. Another approach worked. There have been published "proofs" that were wrong and subsequently retracted, but probably never for as simple an error as dividing by zero.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94742/examples-of-interesting-false-proofs may be of some interest. Also, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35468/widely-accepted-mathematical-results-that-were-later-shown-to-be-wrong

Comment: And maybe https://mathoverflow.net/questions/879/most-interesting-mathematics-mistake and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27749/what-are-some-correct-results-discovered-with-incorrect-or-no-proofs and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257628/theorems-demoted-back-to-conjectures

Comment: I loved your links. Pretty much solve my problem. If you post it as a solution, I will accept it! Tks very much

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions more-or-less closely related to the question here have been asked and answered at MathOverflow, e.g.,
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94742/examples-of-interesting-false-proofs

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35468/widely-accepted-mathematical-results-that-were-later-shown-to-be-wrong

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/879/most-interesting-mathematics-mistake

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27749/what-are-some-correct-results-discovered-with-incorrect-or-no-proofs

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257628/theorems-demoted-back-to-conjectures